# How can I get relative path of the folder in my project ?(iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Suppose, I have added one folder name "Images" in my project.How can I get the path to that folder? My main intention is to get the number of pictures in "Images" folder.

Comment: you want to read from resources folder or documents directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work a bit more on your question: it assumes a lot and requires the reader to guess.

> I have added one folder name "Images" in my project

So I guess this means you added it as a folder reference

> and I want to get it's path

And I guess that you want to do that at run time from your application, not at build-time from Xcode.

If so, you could do something like:

```
NSURL *containingURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL];
NSURL *imageURL = [containingURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images" isDirectory:YES];
NSFileManager *localFileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray *content = [localFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:imageURL includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants error:NULL];
[localFileManager release];
NSUInteger imageCount = [content count];
```

This code does not assume that all images are of the same kind.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"Images"] count];
```

This returns the number of jpg images from the Images folder. This is the case if you added the images to your application bundle.